# Remove the characters after 64 characters of column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen so many ways to remove special characters from column names, and those worked for my example. However, now, I want to remove all extra characters in all columns that are longer than 64 characters in length. Is there an easier way I can do it?

For example:

```
>> df.columns
Index['hi', 'happy_tree_family_is_most_amazing_awesome_fantastic_series_even_in_2021_01_25_and_I_want_to_watch_it_again_ahhahahahahaha']
```

after work:

```
>> df.columns ## 2nd column name only contains 64 character in length ##
Index['hi', 'happy_tree_family_is_most_amazing_awesome_fantastic_series_even_']
```

A million thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[:64]
```

Comment: Is this working with the first row, in which there are totally just 2 characters?

Comment: @windsound this only reduce the longer one below 64, if less than 64 no change

Answer (score -1):

Since **columns** is predefined attribute for dataframe try using the other syntax in case you face any problem

```
df['columns'] = df['columns'].str[:64]
```